# An exercise/solution-based reference on vector calculus

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, vector-analysis

I need to remember several things from vector calculus (line integrals, surface integrals, vector fields, Green's, Stock's & other famous theorems, etc.). Towards this, I'm looking for a resource which is exercise/solution-based just to get my brain refreshed.

What would you suggest?

Comment: The Schaum's Outlines series sounds like a good fit: there's a volume in [Vector Analysis](http://www.amazon.com/Vector-Analysis-Edition-Murray-Spiegel/dp/0071615458), and all of them have a ton of exercises with solutions (and even better, working).

Comment: @Chappers, thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for. Why don't you post this as an answer?

Comment: Okay, have done so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Schaum's Outlines series sounds like a good fit: there's a volume in [Vector Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071615458), and all of them have a ton of exercises with solutions (and even better, working).